# I have an error using the save method in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, methods, sqlite, sqlite3-ruby

I created a `User` model with attributes `name` and `email`. So to create users, I opened the rails console and used the sandbox.

> > rails console --sandbox
> >     user1 = User.new( name: "example" , email: example@org.com)
> >     => #

But when I do

```
>>user1.save
```

I get the following error:

```
1.9.3p194 :012 > user2.save
   (0.3ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "SAVEPOINT": syntax error: SAVEPOINT active_record_1
```

What could the possible error be? Some dependency issue between sqlite3 1.3.6 and activerecord 3.2.5

Comment: Does the error replicate if you dont use `SQlite3` and use any other possible a relation database like `mysql`

Comment: I have not tried it with anything other than SQLite3. Do you mysql would be a better RBMS? I think there is a compatibility issue between sqlite3-ruby 1.3.6 and the on-board SQLite3 version (3.4.0).

Comment: Why dont you use sqlite3 gem that come in build with rails3 application if you dont use any adapter

Comment: Opps did notice you are already using sqlite3 got confuse in the name